# Instalar PCNTL no Ubuntu 16.04 PHP7

Tags: php, ubuntu

Tenho um aplicação GPS que seu manual está escrito para PHP 5, mas gostaria de usar o PHP 7.

Consegui fazer a instalação sem problema, mas quando tenho que instalar o `PCNTL` não consigo.

No PHP 5 o procedimento é esse abaixo:

```
apt-get install dpkg-dev
apt-get install php5-dev
mkdir /tmp/phpsource
cd /tmp/phpsource
apt-get source php5
cd /tmp/phpsource/php5-*/ext/pcntl
phpize
./configure
make
cp /tmp/phpsource/php5-*/ext/pcntl/modules/pcntl.so
/usr/lib/php5/20090626*/
```

Porém não sei como fazer esse procedimento no PHP 7.

Answer (score 2):

Se você instalar o PHP via apt-get, já vem com PCNTL habilitado no Ubuntu. Você não precisa instalar nada.

```
begnini@coffee-machine:~# php -i | grep pcntl
pcntl
pcntl support => enabled

begnini@coffee-machine:~# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```